# Flink 1.19 error Cannot determine simple type name "com"

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

Just updated flink from 1.18 to 1.19. We use flink sql with kafka connector.

We have a jar that contains all customer udf and its uploaded to s3. We create function in flink for these udf using

`create or replace function array_size as 'com.sailpoint.udf.ArraySize' language java using jar 's3://s3_bucket/prefix/saas-idn-dip-udf.jar'`.

When submitting the flink sql code using sql-gateway, seeing error. Right now i am uable to tell where is error is coming from. The same code works in flink 1.18

```
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileError(UnitCompiler.java:13080) ~[flink-table-runtime-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getRawReferenceType(UnitCompiler.java:7175) ~[flink-table-runtime-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
```